# Installing ROS indigo on Raspbian jessie apt-get update fail - Failed to fetch ../../../../..armhf/Packages

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, jessie, ros-jade, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think my problem is with the sources.list file but can not find the proper contents for this installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/239560/installing-ros-indigo-on-raspbian-jessie-apt-get-update-fail---failed-to-fetch-../../../../..armhf/packages/) by [OldBotBuilder](https://answers.ros.org/users/27489/oldbotbuilder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-07-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2016-07-14**:
I think you have to [build ROS from source](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Source). The Debian packages are not for ARMhf architectures. With the exception of Ubuntu for ARMhf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Kinetic is only supported for Debian Jessie on amd64 and arm64 (64-bit ARM) processors; not armhf.

Have a look at http://answers.ros.org/question/239466/incomplete-packages-for-kinetic-armhf-jessie/

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-07-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0